# How can I run cleanup code only for specific tests with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

With pytest is there a way to run cleanup code on a specific test function/method alone. I know we can do this to run for each test function. But here I want to place some cleanup logic specific to a single test function.

I can just put cleanup code at the end of the test. But if test fails then cleanup wont be done.

Comment: Take a look at pytest fixtures in the documentation, you can put the cleanup code after the yield statement in the fixture.

Comment: By default fixture teardown code can run once for all tests in module only once or after each test. I want specific clean up code to run only for one test func

Comment: That depends on the scope of the fixture. May be create a new fixture which can call the setup (or another fixture with setup code) & do the cleanup as teardown in the new fixture.

Answer (score 6):

Create a fixture with your cleanup code and inject it only into the one test by using the fixture as an argument for your test or by explicitly marking the test with the [`pytest.mark.usefixtures`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#usefixtures) decorator.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_cleanup_fixture():
    # Startup code
    ...
    yield
    # Cleanup code
    ...

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('my_cleanup_fixture')
def test_with_special_cleanup():
    pass
```

`my_cleanup_fixture` has scope `function` by default, so the startup and cleanup code will run for each function it is injected.